# Logging errors with Elmah and nHibernate

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, nhibernate, logging, elmah

I'm working on an Asp.Net MVC3 application and we are looking at using Elmah to do our data logging.  We are using fluent nHibernate to handle all interaction with mainframe DB2 database.  So any other DB provider, is not an option.

I've been doing some research on this topic and cannot find any information on how to do it.  Would rewriting one of Elmah DB providers to handle interfacing be appropriate?

I'm looking for some guidance on how to start this or where to look for the guidance.

Comment: Have you taken a look at Log4Net as I don't believe Elmah supports DB2?

Comment: agree with @Jesse comment, if you can use Log4Net.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with the commenters on your question.  Use log4net instead of ELMAH if at all possible.  NHibernate requires log4net, so it will already be present.  In addition to error logging, you can log copious NHibernate stuff (in particular the SQL statements it generates), which I find very useful while building and debugging an application.

With log4net you can send log messages to an Oracle database with the AdoNetAppender.

Answer (score 0):

From my understaning Elmah is implemented as a HTTP Module, and does not use a NH so you would have to write a provider (inherit from ErrorLog), look at the [Oracle](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/source/browse/trunk/src/Elmah/OracleErrorLog.cs) implemation then change the webconfig to point to your class

there is a issue open on the google project site, I would see if you can vote on this, as it would be less work for you, but you may have to wait longer

http://code.google.com/p/elmah/issues/detail?id=257